# Unity Ads Android Integration - Reloading Video Ad issue

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, ads

I have integrated Unity Ads android library into my android project. At the beginning, after calling init

```
UnityAds.init(this, Consts.UNITY_GAME_ID, this);
```

onFetchCompleted method of my callback is called and I can show video and get callback about completion on my activity.

I want to reload video after completion and looking for a method like "reload", "fetch" etc. on UnityAds class. It seems like there is no way to do this.

So, I have tried to call UnityAds.init again, but couldn't get any callback or any error on logs.

How can I reload another video ad?

Comment: What do you mean by reload video after completion. You mean show another video after another video after another video?

Comment: Yes, I want to load another video and show to user.

Answer (score 0):

**1**. You don't call init twice.

**2**. You are probably not using `isReady` to check if the ad is read to be shown before calling `Advertisement.Show()` function.

**Copied** directly from Unity website, the code below should show ad and wait To show another ad, simply call `ShowAd()` again.

```
[SerializeField] string gameID = "33675";

void Awake()
{
    Advertisement.Initialize (gameID, true);
}

void Start()
{
    ShowAd();//Show ad
}

public void ShowAd(string zone = "")
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        StartCoroutine(WaitForAd ());
    #endif

    if (string.Equals (zone, ""))
        zone = null;

    ShowOptions options = new ShowOptions ();
    options.resultCallback = AdCallbackhandler;

    if (Advertisement.isReady (zone))
        Advertisement.Show (zone, options);
}

void AdCallbackhandler (ShowResult result)
{
    switch(result)
    {
    case ShowResult.Finished:
        Debug.Log ("Ad Finished. Rewarding player...");
        break;
    case ShowResult.Skipped:
        Debug.Log ("Ad skipped. Son, I am dissapointed in you");
        break;
    case ShowResult.Failed:
        Debug.Log("I swear this has never happened to me before");
        break;
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitForAd()
{
    float currentTimeScale = Time.timeScale;
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    yield return null;

    while (Advertisement.isShowing)
        yield return null;

    Time.timeScale = currentTimeScale;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is for Unity SDK, I am using Android SDK of unity ads. I also check UnityAds.canShow() after completing a video but it is false which means I can not call UnityAds.show() again directly.

Comment: ?? I know this is for Unity SDK. The code above is for Unity Ad SDK. The code above should do it. Just change `gameID` to your `gameId` then call `ShowAd()` each time you want to show ad. The code above implements ways of waiting for the ad to load before showing. Please try it before making further comments.

Comment: You didn't understand me correctly! My project is not a Unity project, it is a native android project. So your code example is not usable for me.

Comment: Oh I see. I read your question wrong. I suggest you tag Java in your question.